# Different behavor in createing database when inherited base context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, dbcontext

I created a base ef db context, there is nothing in base context, only it inherites from IDataContext interface

```
public abstract class DataContextBaseEntityFramework : DbContext, IDataContext
{

}
```

and my context

```
public class ProjectDataContext :DataContextBaseEntityFramework
{

    public DbSet<Musteri> MusteriListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MusteriAdres> MusteriAdresListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sepet> SepetListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Siparis> SiparisListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SiparisDetay> SiparisDetayListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SiparisVergi> SiparisVergiListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Kategori> KategoriListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Malzeme> MalzemeListesi { get; set; }




    public DbSet<Menu> MenuListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MenuGrup> MenuGrupListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MenuGrupUrun> MenuGrupUrunListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MenuSiparisZamani> MenuSiparisZamaniListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Urun> UrunListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VaryasyonDetay> VaryasyonDetayListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VaryasyonDetayEkMalzeme> VaryasyonDetayEkMalzemeListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vergi> VergiListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Parametre> ParametreListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PostaKodu> PostaKoduListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServisSaati> ServisSaatiListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Slider> SliderListesi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Yonetici> YoneticiListesi { get; set; }

}
```

when i create database it creates only one table named BasedEntites which is my base class for model classes

When i remove the basecontext and inherite onlu IDataContext it works corretly.
Why an empty class makes this behavor?

Comment: Are you using command in Package Manage Console to create the database ?

Comment: Which `IDataContext` interface is this? And have you got any mapping code?

Comment: I created the interface t be able to use in repository pattern, it is empty

Comment: i tried both way to create db, in pm console it alters the first table adds columns which depend on different tables

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of default [Table per Hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.4) behavior. Unless a separate entity configuration(s) is/are provided, it is supposed to behave like this.

Extracted from the link:

> In the TPH mapping scenario, all types in an inheritance hierarchy are mapped to a single table. .... When creating your model with Code First, TPH is the default strategy for the types that participate in the inheritance hierarchy. ...

It is useful to provide [Entity configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) separately using Fluent API, and [`EntityTypeConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) as that offers much more flexibility.

Comment: doesnt TPH means inheritance for pocos? i inherite the context class

Comment: True. And I think for your case, there is a base class that is extended by your POCOs. Thus, I think, this TPH scenario applies for you.

Comment: Yes, i have a base class but when i create my context directly by inheriting DbContext, i get the successfull db creation

Comment: @OkanSARICA I am little bit confused. In you question it says: "When i remove the basecontext and inherite onlu IDataContext it works corretly."

Comment: I inherite base context class, BaseContext:DbContext,IDataContext and ProjectDataContext:BaseContext this is the situation it doesnt create rigth tables. But when i create mycontext like  ProjectDataContext:DbContext,IDataContext it work correctly